# Issues connecting to WPA2 with User Authentication Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac, wpa2, osx-mavericks

I was on all the builds of the Mavericks beta and connecting to my University's network was fine. Then I upgraded to the public release and now I can't seem to connect to the internet. I can connect to other networks, but not my schools. Its a WPA2 network with a User Authentication. And my MacBook is a 2011? 2.2 GHz first gen i7 Quad Core with 8 GBs of RAM. Does anyone else have the same issue? Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Over at apple stackexchange the [same problem's been reported](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106342/wpa2-enterprise-network-doesnt-appear-in-wifi-list-osx-mavericks). In the [Apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23482291#23482291) others have reported this problem, noting that the network is still visible at the command line, but no solution has yet been proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but clicking "Join Other Network" and manually filling in the details works for myself and other people (specifically for WPA2 protected networks). However the computer doesn't remember the details so this needs to be done manually any time the connection needs to be rejoined. Hopefully Apple will release an OS fix soon.